# Question about memory leaks Javascript Windows Gadget (Also in general)

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory-leaks, windows-desktop-gadgets

I was working on memory leaks for a Windows 7 Gadget for awhile, and then got more functionality to implement which I believe made the memory leaks worse/added more leaks.  I ran 4 instances of the gadget for roughly 16 hours and memory usage went from 22,000K to 36,000K.  However, something that perturbed me is that the Handles, USER Objects, and GDI Objects remained roughly the same.  The USER and GDI Objects actually remained exactly the same and the Handles jumped from something like 1026 to 1034 in all that time.  I consider that to just be some eccentricity of sidebar since each of my gadgets refresh every 7 seconds.

I have two questions, in the general case, what kind of memory leaks cause something like this?  And in my case I use Ajax to access web services for this gadget, so if anyone knows what might cause such a thing in Ajax that would be great.

I have already seen articles on main causes of memory leaks in Javascript, I'm just wondering if anyone has any ideas on why the memory would go up so much when the handles and objects stayed effectively the same.  Perhaps there are known causes in Ajax or programming in general for such a case?

Comment: I don't think I'd consider a 14KB increase in size to be a serious problem.

Comment: @Pointy I was using K to signify thousands, I didn't even think about it being read as KB, but that makes sense since Task Manager uses K to signify KB.  I've been spacing out lately.  But yeah it's a 14,000 KB increase.

Comment: So 14 megabytes, in layman's terms, right? Well, without seeing the actual code involved, it's doubtful you'll get a very specific answer.

Comment: @Pointy Yup, 14 megabytes. I know that it'll be hard without code but I can't post all the code, there's a lot going on in this gadget. I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas of generally what caused a memory leak like that (with seemingly no increase in objects) or what might be able to cause one in Ajax.

Comment: Are you using a Javascript library to handle any of the DOM manipulation or Ajax requests?

Comment: @Shakakai I am using Sarissa to get some XML.  However I do everything else manually.

Comment: Also, the memory usage just jumped down to 25,000 K.  Everything else is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely appreciate JS work done without libraries but in a situation like this, you may want to toss JQuery (or Prototype, Mootols, etc) into the mix. They are very well tested for memory consumption with Ajax requests (and DOM manipulation).

You don't need to modify your DOM code at first but try replacing your Ajax requests with JQuery's Ajax methods. Then run your memory tests again. If that eliminates it, you know you've got a memory bug in your XHR code.

Otherwise, its probably related to event handlers in your DOM code not being properly removed before you destroy an element (I'm assuming you remove and add DOM elements at some point). If a handler isn't removed in IE, that will create a memory leak (the DOM element is held in memory indefinitely, suck).

Comment: I do add and remove DOM elements, you would be correct. I have a question though, can JQuery ignore security certificate errors? Right now I have my JS set up to do just that in certain situations. I am fully aware that in the general case that is bad practice, but it is actually necessary in this case.

Comment: Thats a great question - I haven't actually built anything that had to deal with security certificate errors. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 64bit SP1 introduced sidebar.exe memory leak, which you might be affected with. As far as I know, this has not been fixed yet, however [this blog post](http://sysadminspot.com/windows/how-to-fix-sidebar-exe-using-lots-of-memory/) offers a workaround.